# Can someone explain what is this { default: Simplify<Serialize<{ /*...*/ }>> return datatype when using useFetch() in nuxt3 3.8.1?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm fetching data using useFetch() in nuxt3(version 3.8.1)

```
var { data: myFixture, pending, refresh, error } = await useFetch('/api/getFixture').
```

[useFetch return type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljHUp.jpg)

The problem is that I'm receiving data but I cannot access it via attributes myFixture.latestfixtureData.details for example, I mean I can do that but I always get error underline picture bellow

[image]

I upgraded from nuxt3 3.0 to nuxt3 3.8.1(latest version), when I was working with nuxt 3.0 everything worked fine but after upgrade this { default: Simplify<Serialize<{ /*...*/ }>> return datatype is here.

If I access data like this

```
{{ myFixture?.latestfixtureData.result_info }}
```

data will display but in visual code there will be an error *Property 'latestfixtureData' does not exist on type { default: Simplify<Serialize<{ /*...*/ }>> *, but I'm validating data on server side with ZOD so I have my own datatype.

But if I use myFixture?.default.latestfixtureData I receive back undefined

What Am I doing wrong with this new version of nuxt3?? What even is this { default: Simplify<Serialize<{ /*...*/ }>> return datatype

Comment: It's a typescript error which is based on your tsconfig and specific IDE environment.  Remember, typescript doesn't run in the browser, it's just javascript at runtime, so keep doing what works (not using `.default`).  Fixing the error, which exists only in your IDE, will come down to your configuration.  Try sharing your tsconfig and relevant type information.  As it is now, it's not reproducible with the information given so far.

Comment: I ran command ">Volar: Restart Vue server" and it started working for some reason. Thank you for the explanation